# Cannot view all of .jar code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I am having trouble viewing my jar files. All the jar files in the libs directory in my app module show sources not found and allow me the option to attach sources. What exactly should I attach to view these jars in their entirety without the annoying comment "compiled code"?

This is the `build.gradle` file from the app and not the overarching one for the project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree (dir:'libs', include:['*.jar'])
  }
}
```

Here is one of the classes in one of the jars in my libs folder (notice all of the comments and also it is not able to be edited):

```
package net.fortuna.ical4j.data;

public abstract class AbstractOutputter {
    protected static final java.nio.charset.Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    private boolean validating;
    protected int foldLength;

    public AbstractOutputter() { /* compiled code */ }

    public AbstractOutputter(boolean validating) { /* compiled code */ }

    public AbstractOutputter(boolean validating, int foldLength) { /* compiled code */ }

    public final boolean isValidating() { /* compiled code */ }

    public final void setValidating(boolean validating) { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Here is my XML in the libraries folder of my project for one of my jar files if this helps:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="ical4j-1.0.6">
    <CLASSES>
        <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/ical4j-1.0.6.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
        <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.ideaLibSources/ical4j-1.0.6-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Notice where the sources are.

Comment: Just add the jar files from the source to your project

Comment: I already did that... The jar files are in the libs folder of my project.

Comment: You have to add the libs folder to your build.gradle

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`. You should try to use Gradle dependencies and not `*.jars`.

Comment: Every time I click where the zip file where libraries for the jar is located it goes back to saying sources not found.

Comment: Maybe it is helpful that I mention that the classes contained in the jar have a lock symbol next to the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, I figured it out. All I had to do was download( in my case) the source files from github as a zip file. I extracted it with7-zip and then at the top right of the IDE where it says "attach sources" I clicked on the extracted folder. Now I can view all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your gradle.build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This will make your build take under consideration your .jar files

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix the "sources not found" IDE message.

Comment: You are applying it to the wrong gradle file.  You need to apply it to your module.  See an example with my own

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your gradle MODULE file.  You probably added it to your PROJECT gradle file.  See an example of mine of a gradle MODULE file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bruno.stackrest"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```